Logging into an angular app from Windows 11 in a docker container running PostgreSQL gives SQLSTATE[08006] [7]?
As mentioned in the subject line when I try to login to an angular app using Laravel on the backend from Windows 11 using a docker container running PostgreSQL I get the following error: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 9445 failed: Connection refused?
If I do the same thing in DBeaver the connection works as expected!
What could the problem be? Please find screenshots & code below:



Laravel config > database.php file
   'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'),
   ...
   'pgsql' => [
           'driver' => 'pgsql',
           'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
           'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
           'port' => env('DB_PORT', '9445'),
           'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'phone-book'),
           'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'dev'),
           'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '123456789'),
           'charset' => 'utf8',
           'prefix' => '',
           'prefix_indexes' => true,
           'search_path' => 'public',
           'sslmode' => 'prefer',
       ], 
   ...

.env file
    DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
    DB_HOST=localhost
    DB_PORT=9445
    DB_DATABASE=phone-book
    DB_USERNAME=dev
    DB_PASSWORD=123456789


